# how to convert &gt; and &lt; with "<" and ">" within a string if brackets are exist using regular expression

Tags: jquery

I want to replace `&lt;` with < and `&gt;` with > using regular expression if any these brackets or both the brackets exist in a string. so how do I check whether these brackets exist within a string with regular expression and replace any of them with < and > respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'&lt; example string &gt;'.replace(/\&lt;/g, '<').replace(/\&gt;/g, '>')
```